# According to Wittgenstein, what is the relationship between "concept" and "definition"? What are the differences between the two?

Tags: wittgenstein

I'm having trouble understanding the difference. I felt that concept can be reduced to definitions.

Comment: In the *Tractatus*, or *Philosophical Inveatigations* or where? It varies. His views evolved.

Comment: Philosophical investigations. Sorry for not mentioning it